# How to use ros_control with Gazebo AND the real robot hardware?

Tags: automation, ros, gazebo-simu

The [`ros_control`](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) package is a powerful tool controlling, above other, differential drive robots. The [`diff_drive_controller`](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) used for this task takes a linear and angular velocity as input and delivers the velocities of the left and right drive wheel as output. The output is retrieved via a [`hardware_interface`](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control#Hardware_Interfaces).

The [`gazebo_ros_control`](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_control) plugin for the simulation platform [Gazebo](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control) has implicitly embedded a `hardware_interface`, which enables the output of the (simulated) velocities of the left and right drive.

If I start my real `hardware_interface` and Gazebo at the same time, there are two `hardware_interface` existing, which leads to an [error](https://github.com/ros-mobile-robots/diffbot/issues/74).

Therefore, my question is whether there is a workaround to start simultaneously *Gazebo* **and** the real `hardware_interface`?

Comment: Why not just put them in different namespaces?